# solr query does not find word

Tags: solr, schema, wildcard

i have a field which contains

```
... Sie kennen zentrale Stationen des Lebenswegs Muhammads. • Sie ke ...
```

i've configured it like this

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but

```
q=volltext:lebenswegs
q=volltext:Lebenswegs
```

give no results, why?

```
q=volltext:lebensweg*
```

finds the document

i'm using solr 1.4

EDIT:

splitting up the config

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    splitOnNumerics="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

leads to the same result

[image: analyze result]

the analyzer seems to match, but my query result stays empty

Query debug:

```
<lst name="debug">
 <str name="rawquerystring">volltext:Lebenswegs</str>
 <str name="querystring">volltext:Lebenswegs</str>
 <str name="parsedquery">volltext:lebenswegs</str>
 <str name="parsedquery_toString">volltext:lebenswegs</str>
 <lst name="explain"/>
 <str name="QParser">LuceneQParser</str>
 <lst name="timing">
  <double name="time">1.0</double>
  <lst name="prepare">
    <double name="time">1.0</double>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
     <double name="time">1.0</double>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="process">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
     <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
  </lst>
 </lst>
</lst>
```

Comment: By using the solr 1.4 and your configuration i have indexed data and search the keyword you asked. Everything works fine. There should be something else.

Comment: which of the configs did you use? the first or second?

Comment: hm thanks your test solved it: the problem was the length of the original text (86KB) but maxFieldLength was 10000. i increased it and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only reason can be :-

```
<filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
```

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory) :-

> A filter that reverses tokens to provide faster leading wildcard and
>   prefix queries. **Add this filter to the index analyzer, but not the
>   query analyzer**. The standard Solr query parser (SolrQuerySyntax) will
>   use this to reverse wildcard and prefix queries to improve performance
>   (for example, translating myfield:*foo into myfield:oof*). To avoid
>   collisions and false matches, reversed tokens are indexed with a
>   prefix that should not otherwise appear in indexed text.

Hence it seems to work on wildcards but not on normal queries.
You can try to remove it from query analyzer and check.

Comment: hm this didn't change the result, only if i remove the ReversedWildcardFilterFactory from both analyzers it shows but, but then the leading wildcard doesn't work any more any ideas how to get both working?

Comment: Did you restart the Server after the config change ? ALso can you check the Analysis as to what tokens are produces with the index analyses ?

Comment: yes, analyze seems to match something, but when querying i'm getting no results

Comment: and if you turn the debug on what query is formed ?

Comment: i've added the dbug output

Comment: thats strange. Can you reindex the data and maybe check from luke what the document holds.